# Python: Why the data is being inserted in two dicts of a list/dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested-lists

I know this might be a very naive mistake but this has got my nerves from quite a while now.

I have a list of nested dictionaries like

```
grs = [{
    'CS9': {
        'Monday': [{
                1: {
                    'subject': 'ESD',
                    'teacherName': 'Goku',
                    'venue': 'RN 141'
                }
            }, {
                3: {
                    'subject': 'CN',
                    'teacherName': 'vegita',
                    'venue': 'RN 102'
                }
            }, {
                5: {
                    'subject': 'ADA',
                    'teacherName': 'roshi',
                    'venue': 'RN 112'
                }
            }
        ]

    }
}, {
    'CS10': {
        'Monday': [{
                1: {
                    'subject': 'ESD',
                    'teacherName': 'Gohan ',
                    'venue': 'RN 141'
                }
            }, {
                3: {
                    'subject': 'CN',
                    'teacherName': 'Saitama',
                    'venue': 'RN 102'
                }
            }, {
                5: {
                    'subject': 'ADA',
                    'teacherName': 'Mob',
                    'venue': 'RN 112'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
]
```

in short two groups with `Monday` as a node and different `events` at different `slots`

So, what i want to do is i want to update the `Monday` node of `CS10` 
with the data =>

```
tempStuff = [{'subject': 'ESD', 'teacherName': 'Aizen', 'venue': 'RN141'}, 'CS10', 2, 'Monday']
```

so what i do is :

```
for i in grs:
    if tempStuff[1] in i.keys():
        i[tempStuff[1]][tempStuff[3]].append({tempStuff[2]: tempStuff[0]})
```

What i expect to add this code to add another dictionary wiz

```
            {
                2: {
                    'subject': 'ESD',
                    'teacherName': 'Aizen',
                    'venue': 'RN141'
                }
            }
```

which it does but it adds this node to `CS9` as well. i have tried different methods to make the data , and do the insertion in different ways, but the change is taking place in both of the nodes.

why?
any help with that?

**Edit 1**

There is no problem in the cropped `json` i.e i have removed the data from `Tuesday` to `Friday` in both of the nodes for the readability of the `json` in the question as the other nodes didn't matter in the insertion. So i have only mentioned `Monday`.

**Edit 2**

Seems like the problem arises when the `grs` is being created during the runtime what we have done here is that we have declared the grs by our own whereas in my code grs gets "filled" or the data insertion is happening by other loops' conditions. BUT after everything is done, grs is same as we have declared here there is no change. i.e. the `grs` we get after insertion to it and the `grs` we have declared here is exactly same.

**Edit 3**

So, here is the code for which inserts stuff in our mysterious "`grs`" from another nested dict/list (FinalDict).

```
      dataArrange = {}

      for g in groups:  # groups is just a list of groups eg CS10, CS9
            for i in FinalDict: # the data from which i'm putting the stuff to grs
                weekdet = []
                for b in FinalDict[i]['lectures']:
                    lectdetails = []
                    if b[0] == 'Remedial Class':
                        slot = b[1]['slot']
                    else:
                        slot = b[3]['slot']
                        subject = b[0]
                        teacherName = b[1]
                        venue = b[2]
                        lectdetails = {'subject': subject, 'teacherName': teacherName, 'venue': venue}

                    try:

                        if ShortCode[lectdetails['subject']] in ElectiveStuff:
                            continue

                    except IndexError:
                        continue

                    if not lectdetails:
                        weekdet.append({slot: "Remedial Class"})
                    else:
                        weekdet.append({slot: lectdetails})

                dataArrange.update({i: weekdet})
            grs.append({g: dataArrange})

        with open('stuff.txt', 'w') as g:  # here we wrote grs in a file which makes me sad though it solves the problem
            g.write(json.dumps(grs))
```

Comment: what are `grs` and `temps[1] ` ??? If we can't run your code we can't reproduce your error.

Comment: the `grs` is the oblect of the data, i changed the names in the question after my test run and forgot to change in the loop. while writing the question

Comment: For me it works just fine.

Comment: This also works fine for me when I run it.

Comment: @JanZeiseweis check the edit

Comment: @MartinLear edit for readibility the data is larger than that , so i have removed the nodes from `Tuesday` to `Friday` for your readability

Comment: Are you saying that the reduced version you posted is working correctly because you removed some parts?

Comment: @JanZeiseweis Exactly!

Comment: And how are we supposed to help you if we can't reproduce the error?

Comment: as far as i know the length shouldn't matter but i have rechecked this many times

Comment: can you give us an example of what's not working?

Comment: @MartinLear the node i want to add for `CS10` is being added in the `CS9` as well . hold on i'll just put the whole data, but it really shouldn't matter

Comment: I tried it Again yes you are right it is working when we declare the `grs` explicitly but the problem arises when the `grs` is being created on the runtime.

Comment: why would there be any difference? The data structure is the same, correct?

Comment: it is exact monsieur, but what we have done here is that we have declared the `grs` by our own whereas in my code `grs` gets "filled" or the data insertion is happening by other loops' conditions. BUT after everything is done, `grs` is same as we have declared here there is no change

Comment: @MartinLear and @JanZeiseweis i guess i was correct, the problem was with the runtime. with `grs`. So to debug it , i wrote the `grs` to a text file and again read it to insert the data, so by that we aren't changing the values of grs but the object of the file which contains the data of grs, it works fine now, but still what is the problem that is causing this?

Comment: Its hard to know unless we can see the full code.

Comment: I strongly suspect a shared reference while building `grs` - that's what you get when two names (or dictionary keys etc) point to the same object.

Comment: @MartinLear i've added the code for your understanding

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers i edited the reference to grs now

Comment: What is `dataArrange`? Where and how is it defined? Can't you understand what a minimal complete verifiable example is?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers pardon for not mentioning but `dataArrange` is just a empty dictionary and similarly your question will arise what is `ElectiveStuff` , `FinalDict`, `ShortCode` , which makes the question more messy , because then you will ask more details about each of them which i'm afraid i can't share that huge data-set here but can assume that they are just another dicts and lists with are too being initialized/filled/created on the run-time (And not declared implicitly), i hope that helps.

Comment: @PaulNicolashunter please take time to read about what a mcve is and why it's important (actually, most often just writing this mcve let you find out where the problem is) : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, it's a shared reference issue. Here:

```
dataArrange = {}

for g in groups:
    # code here
    dataArrange.update({i: weekdet})
    grs.append({g: dataArrange})
```

you are reusing `dataArrange` over and over and over, so in the end each of `grs[x]{g}` refer to the very same unique dict. You have to understand that Python **never** implicitely copies anything.

The solution is quite simple: instead of reusing the same `dataArrange` dict over and over, create a new one each time.

Comment: yes, building off this, you can just move `dataArrange = {}` into the first for loop instead of leaving it outside and your problem should be solved.

Comment: yes, you are right i'm using the same `dict` , and you are saying that i should take `dataArrange` or another fresh dict inside the loop, but that is not how i want it to work , i don't want a empty `dict` over every iteration, but to fill this till the end of the iteration, though i couldn't understand the second part `You have to understand that Python never implicitely copies anything`